# How to create a python kivy label that's color is stored in a variable that can be accessed by other kivy widget classes and updated during runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have three .kv files that are each for a screen in my app, one is the screen manager and the other two are the actual screens. I need to store the color attribute of a label in one of my screens to a variable in my main app class, this way I can update that variable from my other screen and change the color of the Label in the other screen.

main.py

```
from utils.imports import *
Window.size = (400, 700)


class ScreenM(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Calc(Screen):
# there are a bunch of functions in here to do calculations but i felt there wasn't a need to include them

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Main(App):
    color = rgba("#FFF000")
    def update_color(self):
        self.color = rgba("#000000")
    def build(self):
        return ScreenM()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

main.kv

```
#:include calc.kv
#:include menu_screen.kv
<ScreenM>:
    Calc:
    MenuScreen:
```

calc.kv

```
#:include utils/custom_widgets.kv
<Calc>:
    name: "calc"
    #:set sp dp("5")
    AnchorLayout:
        padding: sp
# Text background Color
        LabelB:
            bcolor: 1,1,1,1

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            BoxLayout:
# Text Panel
                AnchorLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 1
                    BoxLayout:
                        padding: sp
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        AnchorLayout:
                            anchor_y: "top"
                            size_hint: .15, .15
                            LabelB:
                                bcolor: 1, 1, 1, 1
                            ButtonI:
                                source: "resources/images/square_menu_icon.resized.png"
                            Button:
                                on_release: app.root.current = "menu"
                                background_normal: "resources/images/empty.png"
                                background_down: "resources/images/gray_n.jpeg"
# The Label i want to chage the color of
#############
#############

                        Label:
                            text: root.d1
                            font_size: 50 if self.text == '' else min(48,max(30/len(self.text) * 15, 15))
                            color: app.color
#############
#############
#############
# History Panel
                AnchorLayout:
                    padding: sp
                    size_hint: .335, 1
# History Background Color
                    LabelB:
                        bcolor: 1, 1, 1, 1
                    ScrollView:
                        start_pos: 'bottom'
                        padding: 5
                        Label:
                            text: root.history
                            text_size: self.width, None
                            color: 1, 0, 0, 1
                            font_size: 40
                            halign: 'left'
                            valign: 'top'
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.texture_size[1]
# Buttons
            AnchorLayout:
# Buttons Background Color
                LabelB:
                    bcolor: 1, 1, 1, 1
# Main Layout
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    spacing: sp

# Button Row 1
                    BoxLayout:
                        spacing: sp
                        Button:
                            text: "C"
                            on_press: app.update_color()
                            font_size: dp(20)

# i remove the rest of the buttons for simplicity
```

menu_screen.kv

```
<MenuScreen>:
    name: "menu"
    Button:
        text: "change color"
        on_press: app.update_color
        on_press: app.root.current = "calc"
```

When i run this nothing happens to the color, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
class Main(App):
    color = rgba("#FFF000")
```

to:

```
class Main(App):
    color = ListProperty(rgba("#FFF000"))
```

When attributes (like `color`) are set in `kv`, they take the value of the variable at the time the `kv` is evaluated. If you want the widget color to change when the variable changes, the variable must be a [Property](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html).